# How to generate nested lists with awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-sets

I'm using the awesome_nested_set plugin in my Rails project. I'm trying to create nested unordered lists like this, but I'm not having any luck:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>
        Test 2
        <ul>
            <li>Test 2.1</li>
            <li>Test 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Test 3
        <ul>
            <li>Test 3.1</li>
            <li>Test 3.2</li>
            <li>Test 3.3</li>
        </ul>       
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Also, I was hoping to do this with one db query.  There's similar question here with an accepted answer, but the solution does not work for me.
[How to render all records from a nested set into a real html tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372366/how-to-render-all-records-from-a-nested-set-into-a-real-html-tree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a partial to render the children and kick it off with children methods:

in: _tree.html.erb

```
<% content_tag :li, :id => dom_id(menu) do %>
  <span class="handle"><%= menu.title %></span>    
  <% content_tag :ul do %>
   <% for child in menu.children do %>
    <%= render :partial => "tree", :locals => {:menu => child }%>
   <% end %>
  <% end unless menu.leaf? %>
 <% end %>
```

in: show.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "tree", :locals => {:menu => @menu} %>
```

Replace @menu with your object.

Comment: Is it me or this is going to execute a DB query on for each branch?